# XMLTABLE to extract values from CLOB XML with multiple attributes

Tags: xml, oracle, clob, xmltable

I have a CLOB XML column in a table with certain fields which I want to extract. The catch here is that some of these fields have multiple attributes, at times different for different rows. For example:

```
...
<DataPDU>
    <Body>
        <AppHdr xmlns="xyz..." xmlns:xsi="abc..">
            <Fr>
...
```

Is there a way to use XMLTABLE queries to match a path with any attributes? For instance, for the above example, as `path AppHdr[@*]/Fr`?

Currently, the only way I am able to extract the needed fields is by first removing all xmlns attributes that I have seen, and passing that to the XMLTABLE function as in the code below:

```
select x.*
from msg m,
xmltable(
    '\DataPDU\Body'
    passing xmltype(regexp_replace(m.message, 'xmlns(:(bmi|Sw|SwInt|xsi))?="\S+"', ''))
        columns
            sender varchar2(20) path 'AppHdr/Fr/Id/InstnId/FI',
            receiver varchar2(20) path 'AppHdr/To/Id/InstnId/FI'
...
) x
```

I am quite certain that this is a convoluted way of doing what I want. But I am only seeing examples of matching a single attribute with XMLTABLE

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML sample has **namespaces**. That's why there is a need to declare them via `xmlnamespaces (...)`, and use them in the *columns* clause XPath expressions.

**SQL**

```
select x.*
from msg m,
xmltable(xmlnamespaces('xyz...' AS "d"),
    '/DataPDU/Body'
    passing xmltype(m.message)
        columns
            sender varchar2(20) path 'd:AppHdr/d:Fr/d:Id/d:InstnId/d:FI',
            receiver varchar2(20) path 'd:AppHdr/d:To/d:Id/d:InstnId/d:FI'
...
) x
```

Comment: Thank you! I had somehow never understood the reason for namespaces to be added in the xmltable query, but as you described, I added the xmlns value to the namespace. There are other tags which have an xmlns namespace as well which I had to add additionally, and added the prefix to the paths.

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression

```
AppHdr[attribute::*]/Fr
```

select all "Fr" nodes of "AppHdr" ones having any attribute.

(Of course add the namespaces where needed)